# batch file START command without /WAIT

Tags: batch-file

I need to start an exe from a batch file and after it has run it, I want the CMD prompt to exit, without waiting for the application to exit.

By just entering the location of the EXE does not work, it seems to wait for it to exit.

Is there a way to not do that with the START command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CALL instead of START

```
call notepad.exe
echo byby
exit
```